# Get a list option value from an auto populated JSON list and pass to JS function

Tags: javascript, json, undefined

Not confident on how to word this but hopefully it'll make sense.

I have  JSON file that auto populates a drop down list.

```
if(key == "<?php echo $conversionType ?>"){

$("#from").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
```

I need to get the "conversion.name" from that and into my function so I can make the output look much better.

The JSON is such that value is shortened for me whereas the name is what the user sees on the dropdown.

I've tried a few options but either get undefined or an error.

I'm trying to change this output in the function:

```
this.res.val(input +" "+ f +"  =  "+ result +" "+ t);
```

to read input +" "+ from +"  =  "+ result +" "+ to

which would translate into something like

1 foot = 30.48 centimetres.

At the moment it shows as 1 foot = 30.48 cm as cm is the value/id and not the name.

Hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do, apologies for the explanation.

EDIT:
Simplified ample of JSON file:

```
     {
        "value":"sqCentimetres",
        "name":"Square Centimetre (cm&#178;)"
    },
    {
        "value":"sqFeet",
        "name":"Square Feet (ft&#178;)"
    },
```

The JSON is used to create the list depending on what option a user selects.  From that a function is then used to convert different units of measurement.

the "value" from the JSON file is used throughout excluding the name. The name is what I'm trying to pass into the function or access from the function so that the output can be cleaned.

Comment: Your examples are hard to decipher. Try elaborating on what you tried and what the JSON looks like

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it with more info.

Comment: @mplungjan - does that help at all?

Comment: This may help : http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/764W9/

That shows the value being retrieved, I want the actual name instead so "Option 1", "Option 2" etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I needed to use :selected

```
console.log($('#meh :selected').text());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/764W9/8/